# IV used in Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection with default encryption algo AES-256-CBC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, encryption, aes, data-protection

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` for encryption and decryption of my data with the default algorithm (AES-256-CBC). As per my finding, I understand that given the same IV and same plaintext this encryption results in the same cipherText again and again. I have a use case where I need to do a data lookup for a plainText which I might have encrypted earlier and stored in some DB. I don't have an option to fetch from db and decrypt the data to check for a match.

Code example,

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    IDataProtector dataProtector;
    IMyStoreRepository externalStore;

    public MyClass(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, IMyStoreRepository externalStore) 
    {
       this.dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("somePurposeString");
       this.externalStore = externalStore;
    }

    public string GetOrAddValue(string someKey)
    {
        string encryptedKey = this.dataProtector.Protect(someKey); // encrypt the given key

        if (this.externalStore.KeyExists(encryptedKey) // look up in the external store
        {
            return this.externalStore.GetValue(encryptedKey); // return the value if match in external store
        }

       string someValue = "foo-bar-foo-bar"; 
       this.externalStore.Set(encryptedKey, someValue); // setting the value in the external store with encrypted key
       return someValue;
    }
}
```

I am injecting the data protection-related dependencies in `Program.cs` with most of the default configurations.

My question is:

1. What's the IV used for encryption if I use it as per the above code.
2. If I use it in the above manner, will it produce same cipherText for a given plainText. Given that the master key is constant across all the encryption and decryption.

Comment: IV is a random Initial Vector (bit like a salt). You ned to store the IV for each encryption

Comment: I haven't specified anything specific for IV when I initialized the DataProtectionProvider with the default configurations. Do you know what is the default IV used in this case?

Comment: Based on the [Data Protection API official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-5.0), it seems that the protected value is not same if we protect the same value, screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MBsb.png), you could check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per these [documents](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/data-protection/implementation/subkeyderivation.html#data-protection-implementation-subkey-derivation-aad), each `Encrypt` call generates a separate key and a random initialization vector (IV) at least with the default settings i.e AES-256-CBC for payload protection and HMACSHA256 for authenticity. For this reason, we can't generate the same cipherText corresponding to a given plainText.